# How you forward and transform GraphQL queries between GraphQL-services?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, apollo

Coming from the world of REST-microservices I am used to handle dataflow roughly in the following way: 1) receive a request, 2) collect data from possibly multiple other (3rd party? REST?)Microservice and/or do some authorization logic, 3) map my collected data to my desired response format. By implementing GraphQL-services now I am trying to achieve a similar behaviour, but still keeping the benefints of GraphQL, especially avoid overfetching of data.

I have found a solution which involves string manipulation of the query-string and massive abuse of the GraphQL-info-object. To me this way feels very wrong and I am wondering if there is a better solution or if I am missing some fundamental understanding of GrahQL itself. Our tech stack includes nest.js, which in turn relies on Apollo technology. I know there are tools like GraphQL Mesh, which might be somewhat promising, but I am still not sure if it solves my problem entirely and I am even less sure if they can be integrated into our tech stack.

To clarify what I am about to do, consider the following minimalistic example. Say I have a book-serivce which is called directly (or through a gateway) by the client, which defines the following schema:

```
type Query {
  book(id: String): Book
}

type Book {
  title: String
  author: String
  price(currency: String): Float
  productDimension: Dimension
}

type Dimension {
  weight: Float
  height: Float
  width: Float
  depth: Float
}
```

This book-service might for example perform some user-based authorization logic and is going to collect its data from a possibly 3rd party book-api with the following schema:

```
type Query {
  book(id: String): Book
}

type Book {
  id: String
  baseData: BaseData
  prices: [Price!]
  productDimension: Dimension
}

type BaseData {
  title: String
  author: String
  edition: Int
}

type Price {
  value: Float
  currency: String
}

type Dimension {
  weight: Float
  height: Float
  width: Float
  depth: Float
}
```

The schemas are similar, yet different, so the incoming query-string on the book-service needs some transformation in order to get forwarded to the book-api. This is where the ugly string manipulation and info-object-abuse comes in. My book-service resolver will call a getBook-method which actually looks like this:

```
async getBook(id: string, info: GraphQLResolveInfo): Promise<Book> {
    const query = this.buildQuery(id, info);

    // Maybe some user-based authorization logic here?

    const client = new GraphQLClient('http://localhost:2000/graphql');
    const data = await client.request(query);

    return this.map(data.book, info);
  }

  private buildQuery(id: string, info: GraphQLResolveInfo) {
    const originalQuery = info.fieldNodes[0].loc.source.body;
    const selectionSet = info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet;
    const selections = selectionSet.selections as ReadonlyArray<FieldNode>;

    let query = `query{book(id:"${id}"){`;
    if (selections.some((s) => s.name.value === 'title')) {
      query = query + 'baseData{title}';
    }
    if (selections.some((s) => s.name.value === 'author')) {
      query = query + 'baseData{author}';
    }
    if (selections.some((s) => s.name.value === 'price')) {
      query = query + 'prices{value currency}';
    }
    if (selections.some((s) => s.name.value === 'productDimension')) {
      const start = selections.find((s) => s.name.value === 'productDimension').loc.start;
      const end = selections.find((s) => s.name.value === 'productDimension').loc.end;
      const productSelectionString = originalQuery.substring(start, end);
      query = query + productSelectionString;
    }
    query = query + '}}';

    return query;
  }

  private map(rawBook: RawBook, info: GraphQLResolveInfo): Book {
    const result = new Book();

    result.productDimension = rawBook.productDimension;

    if (rawBook.baseData) {
      result.author = rawBook.baseData.author;
      result.title = rawBook.baseData.title;
    }

    if (rawBook.prices) {
      const selections = info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections as ReadonlyArray<FieldNode>;
      const priceNode = selections.find((s) => s.name.value === 'price');
      const relevantCurrency = (priceNode.arguments.find((a) => a.name.value === 'currency').value as StringValueNode).value;

      const priceValue = rawBook.prices.find((p) => p.currency === relevantCurrency).value;
      result.price = priceValue;
    }

    return result;
  }
```

As I said, I don't think this is the intended way to do thing, but it kinda works ... as long as you don't think too much about failure safety. Do have any experience on how to solve this problem in a more concise way? By the way: federation is not an option, because my 3rd party API would not have the apollo-federation specification implemented.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I have a similar use case.

Comment: You might want to look into schema stitching and/or GraphQL Mesh: https://www.graphql-mesh.com/